# Html table (text) to image using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

Can anyone point me to some sample code in C# for converting an html table to image? I know how to convert text to image but i need to create an image of well formatted text. The whole text is formatted in html table.

Comment: Do you mean convert HTML fragment to bitmap?

Comment: Do you mean to convert HTML to Bitmap or PDF?

Comment: one complete HTML table to bitmap

Answer (score 6):

You can use the WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap method.  Here is an [example](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image.aspx).  So what I would do is create a page dynamically with the table you want, and nothing but the table, then use the DrawToBitmap method to save it to an image file.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use http://iecapt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Converting HTML to bitmap is difficult task. You will need first a rendering engine capable of handling HTML and optionally javascript and css (in case you want to support them). Using a [WebBrowser](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2539.htm) control could be done but there might be better ways.