# Convert a div element to image

Tags: c#-2.0

Is there a way to convert HTML inside a div to an image in C# with all its formatting preserved.

Also is there a way to show text inside a div in Print Preview mode.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be so easy. The mostly used method is to let a browser do then rendering and then somehow make it export a "capture" of this page.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769310/html-table-text-to-image-using-c) on SO for some more possible answers.

You could also do a search on [web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)-scraping, which might be helpful.

Comment: Is there a way to find that the web page has been loaded completely.

Comment: You need to give a bit more information than that, where would you like to find out if it's loaded? On the client(javascript), using a component(and which)?

Comment: Actually when I try to convert the document to an image right now I am getting a white image with no contents inside it. I think its because the page hasn't been loaded yet.