# Change HTML table contents to image format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get some idea's about my task. i want to change My HTML table content code to a image format. i did get any idea . can any one please give me an idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: [Darin Dimitrov's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/769363/770710)

> You will need first a rendering engine capable of handling HTML and
>   optionally javascript and css (in case you want to support them).
>   Using a [WebBrowser](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2539.htm) control could be done but there might be
>   better ways.

There are few other options also, Refer the following links:
[Html table (text) to image using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769310/html-table-text-to-image-using-c-sharp)
[How to convert block of html to an image (e.g. jpg) in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165318/how-to-convert-block-of-html-to-an-image-e-g-jpg-in-asp-net)
[Convert a HTML Control (Div or Table) to an image using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972739/convert-a-html-control-div-or-table-to-an-image-using-c-sharp)
[render HTML (convert to bitmap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632280/render-html-convert-to-bitmap)

code snippet:

```
public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url)
{
    // This method gets a screenshot of the webpage
    // rendered at its full size (height and width)
    return GenerateScreenshot(url, -1, -1);
}

public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
{
    // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate(url);
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }


    // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
    wb.Width = width;
    wb.Height = height;

    if (width == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
        wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    }

    if (height == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
        wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
    }

    // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
    wb.Dispose();

    return bitmap;
}
```